# Transformation or relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Could anyone please chack my task on equivalence relation? THank you!!
In this task it says:
if $f\colon X \to Y$ is a transformation. We define the relation $R$ to $X$ :

$x'\sim_R x'' \Leftrightarrow f (x') = f(x'')$
Show if it´s equivalence relation.

reflexive:  yes
x´~ R x´´ <> f(x´) =f (x´´)
1 ~2      <> 4     =4

symmetrical, no

x´~ R x´´ <> f(x´) =  f (x´´)
it´s not clearly defined to which x the image belongs

transitive, yes
x´~ R x´´ <> f(x´) = f (x´´)
1 ~ 2     <>  4    = 4
x´´~ Rx´´´<> f(x´´) = f(x´´´)
2  ~ 3    <>  4     =4
then
x´~ R x´´´<>  =f(x´) = f(x´´´)
1 ~ 3     <>   4     =4

another one Ihave to solve.

There is an amount consisting of three elements $X= \{a,b,c\}$ Give three relations of X with the characteristics:
1) reflexive, not symmetrical, not transitive
2) symmetrical, not reflexive, not transitive
3) transitive, not reflexive, not symmetrical.

Thank you. I would be happy about both, explanation and a way to solve these tasks.
Sophia

Comment: Every transformation induces a relation, but not every relation is a transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, note that you are saying that $x'$ and $x''$ are related if and only if *they have the **same** image under $f$*.

That keyword *same* is a tell-tale sign that you have an equivalence relation. Just try to spell out the three properties, such as *for each $x$, is it true that $x$ and $x$ have the same image under $f$*, and you'll see what I mean.

(By the way, you should see soon in your course that every equivalence relation arises this way.)

For the rest, just play around a bit - this is an exercise from which you can learn something only by trying to do it yourself. Starting with the reflexive/not reflexive part is probably sensible. Show us what you have tried, and you'll get help.

Comment: okay thank you. will try very soon :-)